What is the basis for the equivalency of $y\sin()$ and $x\sin()$ in the problem below?
My math book presents a scalene triangle and gives the left angle as 31.3 ($a$) and the top angle as 104.7 ($b$). It then gives the far side as 6.78 ($x$). The question asks for the length of the base ($y$), and solves for $y$ with the equation
$$y\sin(a)=x\sin(b)$$
(which when factored becomes $y=x\sin(b)/\sin(a)$).
What is the basis of this equivalency?

The Law of Sines.
